# How to install plugin - Non-developer

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am not a developer and I hope someone can help me. I had purchased a Mailchimp Commerce plugin via the plugin store but I don't know how to install it or find any documents on how to.

I do see the license on my ID but it says "Craft License Not attached to a CMS license."

Do I need a developer to install the plugin? any instructions I can look over?

Any help is really apprecited

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: Hey  inrsaurabh, I finally got help from a developer since I couldn't figure it out. Thank you so much, I gave him the links you had provided and it was done very quickly. I am not able to try the plugin and then add the license that I had purchased.

Answer (score 1):

Plugins can be installed through the Craft control panel.

When you log in to your Craft install, you'll see *Plugin Store* in the left-hand menu. From there you can find and install (labelled 'Try' as you're first installing as a trial) the MailChimp Commerce plugin.

Once installed go to Settings > Plugins and enter the license you purchased.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is, I can't see any install options - Have already bought the license

Comment: The problem is I can't see an install button - I have admin privileges. I went into the Plugin store and searched for the plugin - I see only the Checkout button but no intsall.

Comment: You need to click ‘try’, this will install as trial. You can then add license key as above.

Comment: I am not able to install :( https://ibb.co/XCdvVm2. Any suggestion?

Comment: You probably don't have the correct file permissions set: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-2-set-the-file-permissions

Comment: Is that on my account level? I have been given admin. So should a develope either install the plugin or give me access to install right?

Comment: This will need to be something you do on your web server, so yes if you're not comfortable with that then I would get a developer involved.

Comment: I do have access to the web server via terminal. Are there any instructions I can follow?

Comment: Dependent on where your site is hosted they will probably be a guide available, if not it might be something they'd do for you. If you want to have a go yourself you need to look into 'chmod', ie. chmod composer.json 744

Comment: We already have other plugins installed earlier by the dev (not with us anymore) so I presume the plugins folder exists. I can access the server via SSH, is there a way to install the plugin that way?

Comment: Yes, there is and you will probably find the answer by searching around a bit. If you have a go and get stuck then come back here for help.

Comment: Thank you for the help  user3788089 :) WIll reach back if I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

In craft cms 3.
We have the option to install any plugin that hosted on [plugin store](https://plugins.craftcms.com)

1. We can install by composer ( if are a developer or have access to the terminal )
2. Install from the Website admin panel.

I made a small gif.

[image: craftcms plugin install]

Add purchased key.

[image: craftcms key]

Updated:

For folder permission, you can follow [Files & Folders permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755604/7616106)

[image: Craftcms permission]

**Update:**

> If your site is in production mode, then you can not update and install new plugins from the backend.

[image: saurabh ranjan]

Comment: Thank you for GIF. Weirdly I don't see the install button, I have purchased the plugin license and can see it at https://id.craftcms.com/licenses/plugins/15576 although it says Craft License Not attached to a CMS license.

Here is a GIF I made: https://media.giphy.com/media/d8K1vc3AlGpgCSjOsW/giphy.gif

Comment: Here is the full gif: https://gph.is/g/4LNjkWQ

Comment: As per the GIF you provided, i think it's normal, just click on the TRY button first, it will install the plugin, once installed to your website, you can add the key. ( to add the key just go to your-website/admin/settings/plugins and add the purchased key)

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't try it I just purchased the license. I am not able to install it, I am getting an error

https://ibb.co/XCdvVm2

Comment: @Faraz It's saying permission denied means folder and files of your site don't have the proper permission. First try to go back to the previous page in new url and check if the plugin is installed or not. If not then you need to correct the permission. Even a non developer can do , just need terminal.

Comment: thanks. The plugin not installed and I am not able to try it either so guess the permission is not set. I am not able to comprehend what files or folders and what permission it needs hence I am not able to search for steps. I would really appreciate any help, what do I need to change via terminal - I have access to the server via SSH

Comment: @Faraz , it's very easy and simple to set permission but we need to set the correct permission, you can follow https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-2-set-the-file-permissions

Comment: You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755604/7616106 , ( you can try the first mentioned commands, I think it will surely solve the permission issues)